# how to remove error text from the email format checker code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been writing a code for validating forms using javascript/jquery. Following is a code snippet for checking email format. The problem is when I enter invalid email, it recognizes it, but when I go back to this field and enter correct email, the error text still stays even though I have used the 'else' part. How do I remove the error text in this case?

```
if(e1.value!=''){
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.signupForm.email1.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        $("#err_email1").html("Please enter valid email address.");
    }
    status=0;         
}
else{
    $("#err_email1").html("");
    status=1;
}
```

Comment: Attach the function to a keyup event or whatever to recheck the email field when the value is changed.

Comment: adeneo is probably right. you'll need to give us the context in which this is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else block to run the code which removes the error message is only running when the email field is blank, which is presumably not what you want, try the edit below.

```
if(e1.value!='')
{
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.signupForm.email1.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        $("#err_email1").html("Please enter valid email address.");
        status=0;  
    }
    else
    {
        $("#err_email1").html("");
        status=1;
    }
}
```